# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, encoding

i know there is a few questions related to this, but i cant seem to find a specific answer or solution i need

my python django on an aws instance gives me this 
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128) 
error

but in my local it is working perfectly fine, i installed the same requirements needed to run it, it has the same virtual environment, the same version of everything. and i cant seem to find where is the error specially since it is working 100% fine and not on the server im using.

the whole thing error it gives is this: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u23Xn.png) (appearently im not allowed to post images)

i realize its a country with a weird name

Comment: Which python version do you use? (python 2 or 3). Also in the same error page, you can trace where in your code that error happened. It might be that you are using python 2 and your models do not have `__unicode__` method.

Comment: im using python 2.7.12.

it happens when i try to put a country model {{formoffer.country}} into the html that holds all (or at least quite the amount of countries). this model is a dropdown since it is a one to many relationship.

but as i said, it works on localhost, but once i put it on the server it gives me that error. so i was thinking it MIGHT be some server configs. i installed and changed to other languages thinking it might be a weird character, but no luck.